# How to select an option from dropdown not having Select tag using Selenium through Python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to learn selenium but ran into the issue of clicking on dropdown options. Got so frustrated I created an account for this issue.

URL https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSc-3miqMb1Dixi7v4Le-2_SXIzekf0E-sDce1Dp7dRKm9iWqw/viewform

I added the time function part thinking if the option load I can click on it. Sadly it was a fail.

from selenium import webdriver

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.implicitly_wait(5)
browser.get("https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSc-3miqMb1Dixi7v4Le-2_SXIzekf0E-sDce1Dp7dRKm9iWqw/viewform?usp=sf_link")
start =browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span')

start.click()
import time 
time.sleep(2)
startt =browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[6]/span')
time.sleep(2)
startt.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the logic that you can use to select the option.

```
# this will open the list box
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()",driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@role='option'])[1]"))

# this will select the option
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@role='listitem']//span[.='Option 4'])[2]").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on the element with text as **Next** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSc-3miqMb1Dixi7v4Le-2_SXIzekf0E-sDce1Dp7dRKm9iWqw/viewform")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.quantumWizMenuPaperselectOption.freebirdThemedSelectOptionDarkerDisabled.exportOption.isSelected.isPlaceholder span.quantumWizMenuPaperselectContent.exportContent"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.exportSelectPopup.quantumWizMenuPaperselectPopup div[data-value='Option 4'] span.quantumWizMenuPaperselectContent.exportContent"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSc-3miqMb1Dixi7v4Le-2_SXIzekf0E-sDce1Dp7dRKm9iWqw/viewform")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='quantumWizMenuPaperselectOption freebirdThemedSelectOptionDarkerDisabled exportOption isSelected isPlaceholder']//span[@class='quantumWizMenuPaperselectContent exportContent']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='exportSelectPopup quantumWizMenuPaperselectPopup']//span[@class='quantumWizMenuPaperselectContent exportContent' and text()='Option 4']"))).click()
  ```